# MPI: how to limit access to file system?

Tags: c++, c, configuration, mpi, boost-mpi

We have MPI based on 4 clusters with 16 cores each. We have a folder called `notRestricted`. We want to limit access of the application we run with mpiexec to file system - limit its access to write only to that one folder on that one machine we ran it from.

We can inject code into app we run but it is not what we really would want to do... and so all wecan tweak is mpi settings/configuration files, and mpiexec command we call to run our app. Main problemhere is that "Inject a replacement for open(2)" for example would open access to other machines fs which we do not want to.

So how to limit rights of mpi application on mpi cluster we create?

Note: this question is related to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367977/c-linux-how-to-limit-function-access-to-file-system) butis not same.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just run your application as a user who only has write access to that one directory ?

Answer (score 0):

How about [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) (assuming you are running Unix of some flavor)?