# How to redirect file operations calls?

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform

We write a programm. From some point we want to make all operations related to files like opening file, writting to file, reading from file (normal FS calls via standart c++ API) instead of calling some OS default FS api's call our own functions. How to make such thing? How to protect it from assembler hacks? and how to make it undoable (meaning starting from some point in our programm we will not be capable to return to normal OS APIs?)

Comment: "How to make it undoable?" I'm not sure I understand, it sounds like you're asking "how can I be so clever that I don't understand what I'm doing"? :-)

Comment: I've read your other questions related to this topic and I have only 1 thing to say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367977/c-linux-how-to-limit-function-access-to-file-system/6375387#6375387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in writing your own [file system filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968) that would handle that. Such a filter could then decide if it should intercept the function call basing on your criteria or it should just forward the call down to the actual file system.

Comment: is there any analog for such thing for linux?